# Download directory content recursively using wget

Tags: download, wget

I would like to download the directory content from below site, I have tried using wget with different options but none of them seemed to work. Is there any other way to download the content?

[https://www.cs.uni.edu/~okane/Code/Glade%20Cookbook/](https://www.cs.uni.edu/%7Eokane/Code/Glade%20Cookbook/)

Tried below wget commands but none of them worked:

```
 wget -r -l1 --no-parent https://www.cs.uni.edu/~okane/Code/Glade%20Cookbook/
 wget -m -p -E -k -K -np https://www.cs.uni.edu/~okane/Code/Glade%20Cookbook/
 wget -r -nH --cut-dirs=7 --reject="index.html*" https://www.cs.uni.edu/~okane/Code/Glade%20Cookbook/
 wget -r -nH --cut-dirs=7 --reject="index.html*" https://www.cs.uni.edu/~okane/Code/Glade%20Cookbook/
```

Answer (score 0):

The below did the trick,

```
wget -r -nH --cut-dirs=2 --no-parent --reject="index.html*" -m -e robots=off --no-parent https://www.cs.uni.edu/~okane/Code/Glade%20Cookbook/
```